# sharded collection's indexes need to start with the shard key?

Tags: mongodb

I read through the sharding docs on the mongo official site. 
However, I can't an answer for these:

1. Do all of a sharded collection's indexes need to start with the shard key?
2. If I required a TTL index on a field for a sharded collection, and since compound indexes are not supported for TTL, what kind I do in this case? (field != shard key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No. You can have any index on a sharded collection. However, queries which do not include the shard key will be sent to **all** shards. The individual shard will then make use of any existing index, sending back it's result to the `mongos` query router, which in turn will sort the results, if required, and send the result set back to the client. Please read [*Routing Process* in the MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/#routing-process) for further details.
2. The TTL removal is a background process which runs on a date field. Each of your shards will spawn said background process. So you can simply create the TTL index on the date field of your choice. Each individual shard will take care of the documents which are to be deleted.